# Js file not found in react-native android project

Tags: android, react-native, file-not-found

I want to make a app having splash screen with a login page using react-native- navigation.When i compile the code this error occured

[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68bqI.png)

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 0):

Is there any file with name index.android.js in Bni folder? 
If you are using some older version of React native then you may need to copy index.js and name the copied file: index.android.js  or you may upgrade your react native.

Comment: yes , index.android.js file is exist in my BNI folder and am using the latest version